# How to write standard CSV

Tags: apache-spark, export-to-csv

It is very simple to read a **standard CSV** file, for example:

```
 val t = spark.read.format("csv")
 .option("inferSchema", "true")
 .option("header", "true")
 .load("file:///home/xyz/user/t.csv")
```

It reads a real CSV file, something as

```
   fieldName1,fieldName2,fieldName3
   aaa,bbb,ccc
   zzz,yyy,xxx
```

and `t.show` produced the expected result.

I need the inverse, **to write  standard CSV file** (not a directory of non-standard files).

It is very frustrating not to see the inverse result when `write`  is used. Maybe some other option or some kind of `format (" REAL csv please! ")` exists.

---

### NOTES

I am using Spark **v2.2** and running tests on **Spark-shell**.

The "syntatical inverse" of *read* is *write*, so is expected to produce **same file format** with it. But the result of

```
   t.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").save("file:///home/xyz/user/t-writed.csv")
```

is not a CSV file of [rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) standard format, as the original `t.csv`,
but a `t-writed.csv/` folder with the file
`part-00000-66b020ca-2a16-41d9-ae0a-a6a8144c7dbc-c000.csv.deflate  _SUCCESS`
that seems a "parquet", "ORC" or other format.

Any language with a complete kit of things that "read someting" is able to "write the something", it is a kind of [orthogonality principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set).

#### Similar that not solves

Similar question or links that not solved the problem, perhaps used a incompatible Spark version, or perhaps *spark-shell* a limitation to use it. They have good clues for experts:

- This [similar question pointed by @JochemKuijpers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31937958/287948): I try suggestion but obtain same ugly result.
- [This link](https://fullstackml.com/how-to-export-data-frame-from-apache-spark-3215274ee9d6) say that there are a solution (!), but I can't copy/paste `saveDfToCsv()` in my spark-shell  (*"error: not found: type DataFrame"*), some clue?

Comment: `simple small and standard CSV file` <-- there's no such thing... A CSV file is simple, for humans. It is, basically, uncompressed text, so, can't be small. And there's no standard CSV.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, sorry, I corrected question's text. I am using a CSV file for read/write configuration and  to post results of (big data) summarizations... Small CSV files, no "big data CSV".

Comment: `very simple (one line) ` -> Note that putting all your code on one line does not make it more simple. Typically it will be *harder to read, understand and reason about*, instead of easier if you create lines with more than one statement or function call on it.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers, make sense, I edited the question, that is not the point.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Can you give an example of the formatting issue? It's hard for us to think about any of this without replicating the set-up. Do you need spark to produce the CSV in a format you like, or is it okay to do post-processing on it?

Comment: Hi @JochemKuijpers, read the NOTE: I is not complete?  There are a description of the function and of its ugly result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862796/1806348 might help. Other than this quick search on existing questions, I'm not to help you I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks the link @JochemKuijpers, I try... But the result of my tests on spark v2.2, in spark-shell, is the same that I reported: the result is not a file but a folder with ugly files... I try `t.write.option("header", "true").csv("file:///C:/out.csv")`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: @PeterKrauss For what it's worth, I agree with your core premise - spark has done something quite nasty here by having `.write.format("csv")` be unable to generate something that can in turn be re-read by `.read.format("csv")`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Spark because you're working with "big"* datasets, you probably don't want to anything like `coalesce(1)` or `toPandas()` since that will most likely crash your driver (since the whole dataset has to fit in the drivers RAM, which it usually **does not**).

On the other hand: If your data **does** fit into the RAM of a single machine - why are you torturing yourself with distributed computing?

*definitions vary. My personal is "does not fit in an excel sheet".

Comment: No, the "Big Data Universe" **is not an island** (!), I need to interact with [small datasets](https://github.com/datasets) to join and normalize data, or to generate and **publish summarizations**... So, as expressed in the question, I need to generate **standard** files for CSV or JSON little files (in real-world for summarizations or for update datasets of joins -- see link).  All programmers and Spark-data analists not say but do it... But with Scala the source-code  that I have access are all ugly using direct `println()` to generate JSON and CSV small files.

Comment: "summarizations", Big Data is reduced to small data by aggregate functions https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)

Comment: k, got it. What's the next tool in your pipeline?

Comment: I was looking for standard Java packages or a Github Scala CSV-writer... Any one that is (reliable and) easy to install and maintain. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

if the dataframe is not too large you can try:

```
df.toPandas().to_csv(path)
```

if the dataframe is large you may get out of memory errors or too many open files errors.

Comment: Hi, good answer (!).  [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) have good plugins for many frameworks, in particular its  dataframe is compatible with Apache Spark... But unfortunately  Pandas is not a  standard module of "Spark ecosystem", so there are no  `toPandas()`  for example in Scala Spark. Main standard methods are in Scala or [all Scala/Python/Java](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html).