# DF passed as parameter is not working, task not serializable

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

Using spark-shell to test a function,

```scala
def smallDfToCSV(fname: String, df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) : Unit = {
  import java.io._
  val pw = new PrintWriter(new File(fname))
  val header = df.head.schema.map(r=>r.name)
  pw.write( header.mkString(",")+"\n" )  // fine 
  df.limit(5000).foreach(    r => pw.write(r.mkString(",")+"\n")  ) // error!
   // org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  pw.close
} // \csvWr

val df = spark.sql(query)
smallDfToCSV("./lixo.csv", df)
```

The error not make sense because it is running:

```scala
df.foreach(  r => println(r.mkString(","))  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task cannot be serialized because `PrintWriter` does not implement `java.io.Serializable`. Any class that is called on a Spark executor (i.e. inside of a `map`, `reduce`, `foreach`, etc. operation on a dataset or RDD) needs to be serializable so it can be distributed to executors.

I'm curious about the intended goal of your function, as well. Since this function will be executed on your executors, you're going to get partial contents of `df` written to `lixo.csv` in whatever the current working directory is for your various executors. If you're intending instead to write the entire contents of `df` to a file on your local machine, you must first take it out of the RDD via `collect`.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, you are right (good explanations!), "first take it out of the RDD". So, another solution for small datasets (as my edited example now using `limit`) is to **use `take(n)` method**, something as `df.take(5000).foreach(  r => pw.write(r)  )`. About your curiousity, the function `smallDfToCSV()` is a simplification of my real-world function.... Imagine a debug to dump small datasets.

Comment: Glad to help! If you want to avoid `take()`, `collect()`, or `sample` , I've had success using a logging framework such as logback to write debug information to Spark's executor logs, which can then be read back via the Spark web UI. This is a good overview of how to do it via log4j: https://mapr.com/blog/how-log-apache-spark/